# Check if all invoices are paid

Tags: sql, invoice

Im banging my head against the wall. I hope you can help

I have the following columns in my invoice table:

| InvoiceNo | InvoiceDate | InvoicePaidDate | JobNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

each JobNumber value will have 1 or more InvoiceNo
I have a variable ('JobNo') that I will receive from an external system
I need to use this variable to check :

1. Check each invoice attached to the JobNo variable is paid or not using the InvoicePaidDate and return a string "Invoice 1234 IS PAID" or "Invoice 1232 IS NOT PAID", and
2. Return 1 additional string if all invoices **are** paid "ALL INVOICES ARE NOW PAID"

Is it possible to do this with a single query?

Im stuck with a rumentary select statement:

```sql
Select Case
    When InvoicePaidDate IS NULL then 'Invoice ' + InvoiceNo + ' Is Not Paid yet'
    else  'Invoice ' + InvoiceNo + ' Is Paid ' END as PaymentStatus
From Invoices
```

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected result

Comment: Please clarify which sql server you are using

Comment: Do you want a row per JobNumber?  Is the all paid tagged onto that column, a different column or different row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this

```
DROP TABLE invoices1;

CREATE TABLE invoices1 (
  InvoiceNumber varchar(10),
  JobNumber varchar(10),
  InvoiceDate date NULL,
  InvoicePaidDate date NULL
);


INSERT INTO invoices1
  VALUES ('1', '1', '2022-05-01', NULL),
  ('2', '1', '2022-05-02', NULL),
  ('3', '2', '2022-05-02', '2022-05-03'),
  ('4', '2', '2022-05-03', '2022-05-04');

DECLARE @jobNo int = 1;
SELECT DISTINCT
  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT
        1
      FROM dbo.invoices1
      WHERE JobNumber = @jobNo
      AND InvoicePaidDate IS NOT NULL) THEN 'ALL INVOICES ARE NOW PAID'
    WHEN InvoicePaidDate IS NULL THEN 'Invoice ' + InvoiceNumber + ' Is Not Paid yet'
    ELSE 'Invoice ' + InvoiceNumber + ' Is Paid '
  END AS PaymentStatus
FROM Invoices1
WHERE JobNumber = @jobNo;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this :

```
Select Case
    When InvoicePaidDate IS NULL then 'Invoice ' + InvoiceNo + ' Is Not Paid yet'
    else 'Invoice ' + InvoiceNo + ' Is Paid ' END as PaymentStatus
From Invoices
Where JobNumber = @JobNo
UNION
SELECT 'ALL INVOICES ARE NOW PAID' as PaymentStatus FROM Invoices
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Invoices WHERE JobNumber = @JobNo) = 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Invoices Where JobNumber = @JobNo AND InvoicePaidDate IS NOT NULL)
```

[SQL fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vzjiIbDO)

Comment: You can union with an `if` statement?

Comment: @Magnus Thanks for pointing this, I corrected the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Distinct
    Case
        When count(InvoicePaidDate) over () = count (*) over () then 'All Invoices Paid'
        When InvoicePaidDate Is Null then 'Invoice ' + InvoiceNo + ' Is Not Paid'
        Else 'Invoice ' + InvoiceNo + ' Is Paid'
    End as PaymentStatus
From Invoices
Where JobNo = @JobNo;
```